# Simplifying nested multiplications in a math expression

Tags: f#, symbolic-math

I have the following union as my AST for a symbolic math expression:

```
type Expr =
| Const of float
| X of float * float
| Sum of Expr * Expr
| Mul of Expr * Expr
| Pow of Expr * Expr
| Sin of Expr
| Cos of Expr

static member (+) (e1,e2) = Sum(e1,e2)
static member (*) (e1,e2) = Mul(e1,e2)
static member (/) (e1,e2) = Mul(e1, Pow(e2,Const -1.0))

let (!) e = Mul(Const -1.0,e)
let (^) e n = Pow(e ,n)
```

**The Problem:**

*I am trying to simplify expressions like `Mul(Mul(expr1,expr2),expr3)` or `Mul(e,Mul(e1,e2))` or generally when there are n-nested multiplications in an expression.*

I wrote this `simp` function that takes an `Expr` and recursively simpilifies things down. (just some algebra), two rules of this functions (read the comments in the code) are causing infinite recursion when the function `simp` is called from `fullSimp`

```
let rec simp expr =
    match expr with
    | Mul(Sum(e1,e2),e) -> simp (e1*e) + simp (e2*e)
    | Mul(e,Sum(e1,e2)) -> simp (e1*e) + simp (e2*e)
    | Mul(e1,e2) when e1 = e2 -> simp e1 ^ Const 2.0
    | Mul(Mul(e1,e2),e) -> Mul(simp (e1*e),simp e2) // adding this rule makes the function 'fullSimp' recurse infinitely
    | Mul(e,Mul(e1,e2)) -> Mul(simp (e2*e), simp e1) // same as above
    | Mul(e1,e2) -> simp e1 * simp e2
    | Cos e -> Cos(simp e)
    | Sin e -> Sin(simp e)
    | _ -> expr
```

and then there is the function `fullSimp` that calls `simp` until `simp` returns no change to the simplified version of the expression

```
let rec fullSimp e = 
    let simplified = simp e
    if simplified <> e then fullSimp simplified
    else simplified
```

Trying to evaluate the following expression yields an infinite recursion!!!

```
fullSimp (Mul (Mul (Const 2.0,Cos (X (1.0,1.0))),Sin (X (1.0,1.0)))) 
// notice the nested multiplications here
// also notice that this does not simplify any furthur so the function 
// should return the same input.
```

Removing the two rules from `simp` solves the infinite recursion but not problem of simplifying the nested multiplications.

**Edit:** To think about the problem differently, I am trying to collect (multiply) constants and varibales that are in nested mulitplication nodes. For example I am trying to take an expression like

`Mul(Const 5.0,Mul(Mul (Const 2.0,Sin (X (4.0,2.0))),Mul (Cos (X (4.0,2.0)),X (8.0,1.0))))`

and turn it into `Mul (Mul (X (80.0,1.0),Sin (X (4.0,2.0))),Cos (X (4.0,2.0)))` which can't simplified any furthur

**Note**: *According to feedback in the comments I edited this a couple of times. Now hopefully it is clear what the problem is. Apologies for the inconsistencies.*

Comment: Can you post a complete-minimal portion of the code that reproduces the error?

Comment: @Gustavo I don't get an error, adding the rule `Mul(Mul(e1,e2),e) -> Mul(simp (e1*e),simp e2)` would get the program stuck for example when fully simplifying the derivative of tan(x), that gets parsed as sin(x) * cos(x)^-1.

Comment: I know, that will be a reproduction of the problem. But the code you posted is incomplete, it doesn't compile.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Gustavo I know, I thought the rest of the code would be irrelevant since the the preblem is specific to multiplication. do I need to post the whole program?

Comment: @ZaidAjaj : It's easier to diagnose your problem by debugging the code rather than just reading it out of context, and one cannot debug code without being able to build it first...

Comment: @ildjarn I will try that, I wrote the program in a script file so F#-interactive was my debugger.

Comment: This can't possibly be right: `| Mul(Sum(e1,e2),e) -> simp (e1*e) + simp (e2*e)` as `e1,e2,e` are all `expr` not `float` so `*` won't work

Comment: @JohnPalmer I added those for the type `static member (*) (e1,e2) = Mul(e1,e2)` and `static member (+) (e1,e2) = Sum(e1,e2)` for readability purposes

Comment: OK, you know those static members but we don't since you didn't specify them in the code. That's the whole point, if the code you post is not complete we will be facing errors that are not the real problem. The you post should be minimal and at the same time complete, that means it should compile (or eventually throw a compiler error if that's your problem) if it's copy-pasted-executed in an fsi session.

Comment: @Gustavo Ok then I will post the code you can compile and check.

Comment: Now your code compiles but the line that it's supposed to reproduce the error don't. Parse and D are not defined. Try at the same time to remove some unnecessary details from your code in order to reproduce the error easily. You may find the solution yourself while doing this.

Comment: @Gustavo try `fullSimp` on the expression `Mul
    (Mul (Const 2.0,Pow (Sin (X (1.0,1.0)),Const 1.0)),
     Mul (Cos (X (1.0,1.0)),Const 1.0))` when the rule `Mul(Mul(e1,e2),e) -> Mul(simp (e1*e),simp e2)` is included in the function `simp` it gives the "error" (freezes)

Comment: @ZaidAjaj - please read this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The answer as a question: what happens if you remove every single rule except the problematic one? from `simp`

Comment: @JohnPalmer What happens? Nothing! Still gives infinite recusion and pattern matching will fail if the last pattern (wildcard _) is omitted

Comment: This was a hint - once you understand why that happens you will understand why the original version crashes

Comment: @JohnPalmer I do understand why it fails. I just can't figure out the best solution. What I did so far is to exaust every possible pattern (added some 20+ patterns that seem to do the job for now)

Answer (score 1):

Man, you've created a monster. Whatever you're trying to do with that, there must be a better way to model it than a 40-cases long match.

This is what I distilled your simplified version to:

```
let rec simp expr =
    match expr with
    | Mul(Mul(e1,e2),e) -> Mul(simp (e1*e), simp e2)
    | _ -> expr
```

When you try it on your test expression, you'll see that it just oscillates between two states:

```
[Mul (Mul (Const 2.0,Sin (X (1.0,1.0))),Cos (X (1.0,1.0)));
 Mul (Mul (Const 2.0,Cos (X (1.0,1.0))),Sin (X (1.0,1.0)));
 Mul (Mul (Const 2.0,Sin (X (1.0,1.0))),Cos (X (1.0,1.0)));
 Mul (Mul (Const 2.0,Cos (X (1.0,1.0))),Sin (X (1.0,1.0))); ...]
```

Which really isn't surprising, given that all that case does is switch around `e` and `e2` expressions (which is further obscured by the fact that you overload `(*)`). This case is just an infinite loop in a box.

What you probably want to have is some kind of backtracking algorithm that will pull out of this kind of looping scenario once it detects the loop. A first hack at putting something like that in place would be to accumulate all the previously visited expressions and skip the case if it gets you to a state you've already seen.

Comment: I now added a `length` function that would check for the number of nodes, since the oscillating expressions are mathematically the same, only checking for object equality isn't enough. so now with `length` a change in a simplified expressions can be detected.

Comment: I already had the "solution", but thanks for the answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I was looking for:

to escape inifinte recursion, or actually not to enter it in the first place was to modify the `fullSimp` function as it only check whether two expressions are "equal", so now it also checks whether the *number of nodes* has changed after simplification so I added this length function:

```
let rec length expr = 
    match expr with
    | Const _
    | X(_,_) -> 1
    | Sum(e1,e2)
    | Mul(e1,e2) 
    | Pow(e1,e2) -> 1 + (length e1) + length (e2)
    | Sin(e) | Cos(e) | Exp(e) | Log(e) | Sinh(e) | Cosh(e) -> 1 + (length e)

let notSameLength e1 e2 = 
    length e1 <> length e2
```

I then replaced the 25+ patterns with those, looking at the gaurds, it only changes order of multiplication when it "makes sense", i.e. when things *CAN* simplify furthur:
(I know, I am calling `simp` twice here, it is not yet fully optimized)

```
| Mul(Mul(e1,e2),e) 
| Mul(e,Mul(e1,e2)) when notSameLength (e1*e) (simp (e1*e)) -> Mul(simp (e1*e),simp e2) 
| Mul(Mul(e1,e2),e) 
| Mul(e,Mul(e1,e2)) when notSameLength (e2*e) (simp (e2*e)) -> Mul(simp (e2*e),simp e1)
```

and finally `fullSimp` becomes:

```
let rec fullSimp e = 
    let simplified = simp e
    if simplified <> e && (length simplified <> length e) then fullSimp simplified
    else simplified
```

Every example I tried so far does simplify nicely so I think this is the solution.

Comment: This "works" only as long as every transformation step decreases the node count. That might be alright for the subset of solutions that you're interested in, but it's a bold statement to throw in a vacuum. Intuitively you're cutting off a large part of search space with it.

Comment: @scrwtp You are right, this will probably not work for certain examples but I couldn't come up with an example that doesn't "work". However, this is only a rewrite-operation and is only for purposes of pretty-printing, the expression stays the same (mathematically), so any manipulation furthur down the line will not be affected.